# Guice scope for scheduled job run

Tags: scope, guice, cron4j

My application is built on top of Guice and runs scheduled jobs (cron4j), which are showing some issues related to inherently @Singleton instances.

The appropriate solution to my problem seems to have Scope that would be applicable for each **job run**, instead of the Singleton one. It would be similar to the Request scope, but in this different scenario.

I've read the [docs for Custom Scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomScopes), but it isn't clear to me on how a given dependency would know on how to request an specific scoped instance from guice.

Example:

```
public class MyJob {
    /* Knows its "run id", which could be used for the scoping mechanism */

    @Inject private Dependency dep;
    public void run() { ... }
}

public class Dependency {
    /* Technically does not know the "run id" from the job */

    @Inject @Named("jobRunScope") private InnerDependency innerDep;
}
```

I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the source for RequestScoped](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/97d4c3621853e7c9c618db0e4e1a84c8ef3a88ca/extensions/servlet/src/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletScopes.java#L47-L146), you'll see that it uses a `ThreadLocal` to store a special `Context` map, holding all of the key-object pairs for the current request.

If your jobs run in a single thread, you could use a similar strategy to store scoped singletons.

Another option would be to create a new `Injector` instance for each job.